# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db err run node app.js in terminal

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker-compose, webapi

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const connectDB = async () =>{
    try{
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:example@db:27017/',{useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true});
        console.log("MongoDb Connected");
    }
    catch(error){
        console.error(error.message);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

module.exports = connectDB; //the error code I was expecting
```

i think there may be an error in the last code
the error code I was expecting

module.exports = connectDB;